# Calculating total value based on dropdown 3 different dropdown value and one column with single line of text data type in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have 5 column, column1: choice with value(A,B), column2: single line of text(appears when I click option "A" from column1), column3: single line of text (appears when I click option "B" from column1), column4: single line of text (I enter amount in it), column5: Calculated column (that gives output). so I'm trying to get the sum in column5(when column2 multiplied by column4) or  to get the sum in column5(when column3 multiplied by column4).

what formula I can apply in calculated column5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with the following formula:

```
=IF([column1] ="A", VALUE([column2])*VALUE([column4]), VALUE([column3])*VALUE([column4]))
```

It uses the [VALUE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/value-function-1fc46e51-4a25-4ba0-bce2-512dd5d4d872) formula for converting the text to number before multiplying operation.